# Programmatically get webform submitted field values

Tags: 7, webforms

How can i print/echo the submitted value of specific field in from a webform? I need to do this in the webform 2 PDF module so i can better customize the output of generated PDFs. Im fairly new to Drupal so an example of how to get a simple f_name filed would be great.

I'd also like to start getting more involved with the Webform API too.

i.e

First Name: SUBMITTED NAME VALUE

Answer (score 4):

To get webform values right after the page submit, they're stored in the global `$_POST` variable.

Alternatively you need to load the right webform submission.

#### Drupal 7

Here is example how to do it in Drupal 7 (as per this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/110567/1908)):

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid'=> 123));

foreach ($submissions as $submission){
    foreach ($submission->data as $row=>$data){
        print '<pre>'; print_r($row); print '</pre>';
        print '<pre>'; print_r($data); print '</pre>';
    }
}
```

#### Drupal 8

Here is the example to get the webform submission in Drupal 8:

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('my_webform');
$form = $entity->getSubmissionForm();
$elements = $form['elements'];
```

Here is the example using `drush`:

```
drush ev 'print_r(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("webform")->load("repairs_taps")->getSubmissionForm()["elements"]);'
```

Comment: This is no longer the best way for Drupal 8+. It should be `$entity->getElementData($field_name)`, or `$entity->getData()` to get all the data.

Answer (score 2):

In recent 3.x and 4.x versions of [webform it has an hook based API](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!webform!webform.api.php/7) to allow you do stuff with submitted webform values.

Look at like [hook_webform_submission_insert()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) or [hook_webform_submission_update()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_webform_submission_update/7) (if your webform has Drafts enabled for instance the final submission is an UPDATE call with isNew == False and isDraft == False).

The functions take a parameter `$submission` that is a PHP array of the submitted form values ... You can do whatever you want with them from there.

Comment: Correction: The $submission parameter is a stdClass object, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 5-7 it looks like one can use the [`webform_get_submissions`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7) function.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 8 solution**:

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('my_webform');
$form = $entity->getSubmissionForm();
$elements = $form['elements'];
```

At the moment there is no function webform_get_submissions() in Drupal 8 (as exists in D7 and D6). Above lines can help to get the submissions of a specific webform.