# fetching records from webform_submitted_data table through following source code but showing error

Tags: webforms

How to display the records from the table by using the following source code?

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in eval() (line 20 of /var/www/module(80)
>   : eval()'d code).

```
<?php
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform').'/includes/webform.submissions.inc');
$query = db_select('webform_submitted_data', 'u');
$query->fields('u', array('sid','nid','data'));
$query->condition('nid','159','=');
$results =$query->execute();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>  Profile Photo </th>";
echo "<th> Faculty  Name and Department  </th>";
echo  "</tr>";

if ($record = $results->fetchAssoc())
{
$sid = $record['sid'];
$nid = $record['nid'];
$submission = webform_get_submission($nid,$sid);
echo "<tr>";
echo $val = $submission->data[15][0];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

You can retrieve node webform all submissions using  [webform_get_submissions](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7) which accepts an array of filters.. As per the error you mentioned in the question seems like below code is causing problem

```
echo $val = $submission->data[15][0];
```

I would suggest printing the information that you got before you try to fetch the data so that you know you are correclty accessing the array results.. print_r will assist you to see the results..

```
module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid'=> 159));

foreach ($submissions as $submission){
    foreach ($submission->data as $row=>$data){
        print '<pre>';print_r($row);print '</pre>';
        print '<pre>';print_r($data);print '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Extract the information you want from $row and $data ...

Comment: Hello. Would you mind adding some explanation to your code? Code-only answers tends to leave people clueless, even if it gets the job done for them/

Comment: Just updated the answer with details.. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote, you should consider using `theme_table` to print a table, preferably using a renderable array ( as opposed to `theme('table',.. )` ).

If you print everything manually, it's easy to forgot a tag, which might then completely screw up your layout :)

You can read more about `theme_table` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) and renderable arrays [here](https://drupal.org/node/930760)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you are planning on generating your own HMTL then use the following to view the data.

```
module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(1111);
krumo($submissions);
```