# Which hook can I use to retrieve form values after submitting a webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

As the title suggests, I would like to know what is the correct hook for retrieving datas after a submission. The goal is to do a task based on the value of a data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is too broad and there are too many possible answers. You can add submit callbacks to a Webform the same way as to any FAPI form. Depending on the version you might also find webform specific hooks (D7) or plugins (D8).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am on a version 8.6.13. In fact my question is in which hook I can put my code which is to do a certain task according to the value of a data of the webform. for example, does a hook_webform_submission_submit exist?

Comment: In D8 use a submit handler plugin, see https://cornel.co/article/create-webform-submit-handler-drupal

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [webform_get_submissions](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7) to retrieve this data.

I also believe this question has been answered earlier with example. Refer

- [fetching records from webform_submitted_data table through following source code but showing error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110564/fetching-records-from-webform-submitted-data-table-through-following-source-code/110567#110567)
- [Programmatically get webform submitted field values](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/240030/18756)